# SQL Query not showing results. The query is to list the names of all the actors who played in the movie 'Anand'

Tags: sqlite

Please see the tables:

[image: tables]

[image: tables]

Sub-Query Method:

```
select p.Name from Person p where p.PID in 
(select mc.PID from M_Cast mc where mc.MID in 
(select m.MID from Movie m where lower(title)='anand' ))
```

Even join is not working:

```
select p.Name 
from Movie m 
join M_Cast mc on m.MID = mc.MID 
join Person p on mc.PID = p.PID 
group by m.MID 
having lower(m.title)='anand'
```

Comment: Which database are you using? You tagged multiple ones.

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: I am using Sqlite3 with pandas and executing this in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your first query works without errors and if you make adjustments like in my few next steps the second one will work also.
2. Your second query: you can not select only p.Name and group by only m.MID. If it is in select clause and is not a part of aggregate function then you have to use it in group by clause. For example like this:

   ```
   select p.Name 
   from Movie m 
   join M_Cast mc on m.MID = mc.MID 
   join Person p on mc.PID = p.PID 
   group by p.Name;
   ```
3. Your second query also has a HAVING clause `having lower(m.title)='anand'` but it should be in where clause like this:

   ```
   select p.Name 
   from Movie m 
   join M_Cast mc on m.MID = mc.MID 
   join Person p on mc.PID = p.PID 
   where lower(m.title)='anand'
   group by p.Name;
   ```
4. Now that both query are working you need to check if you have a movie with title 'ANAND' in your data. Also you need to check if you have a corresponding MID and PID data in other tables.
5. I have tested this in MySQL but it will maybe help you even if you use other database to guide you through some mistakes... [Here is a small DEMO in MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2211aa2104ecbafacad2c1990a1ed8f3) where you will see that data will not be returned if there is no data in one table.
6. Here is a small DEMO for SQLite where you can see that your first query is working:
   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3ec44/1
   and here is a small DEMO where you can see that my code is working:
   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3ec44/2
   Please check the data!
7. After I have exchanged few comments with OP I have noticed that maybe it is a blank space in data making a problem. So I suggested this:

   ```
   select p.Name 
   from Person p 
   where trim(p.PID, ' ') in (select trim(mc.PID, ' ')
                              from M_Cast mc 
                              where mc.MID in (select m.MID 
                                               from Movie m 
                                               where lower(title)='anand'))
   ```

This also can be implemented in the second query:

```
    select p.Name 
    from Movie m 
    join M_Cast mc on m.MID = mc.MID 
    join Person p on trim(mc.PID, ' ') = trim(p.PID, ' ') 
    where lower(m.title)='anand'
    group by p.Name;
```

The problem was that in the query two tables were joined with `mc.PID = p.PID` and one column had data with blank spaces. So the query was trying to join this data :  `' 1' = '1'`. TRIM function will remove all the blank spaces in the value and join will then be possible.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am afraid it's still not working, for the first query there is no name displayed and for the second it shows an error if I change "having" to "where". I am using sqlite3 and pandas and executing all this in jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Raturi have you read what I have written ? Do you have data in your table Movie with the name "Anand" ? Also, it is not just to replace having with where it is a location of the command that is also important. Please check my answer in more details again.

Comment: Hi @SudhanshuRaturi please check my comment and updated answer.

Comment: yes I have read your answer and yes there is a record with title as anand, and I took care of the location as well

Comment: Ok, have you checked that there is a corresponding data in other two tables (PID and MID values)? Have you seen that the query works in my demo ?

Comment: yes I have checked there is data on the other tables as well and yes I have seen the demo. I don't know why it doesn't work in jupyter notebook. till inner 2 subqueries it totally works fine and show about 16 results but when I add the third and final outer query then nothing shows up

Comment: Ok, I understand, please check also this: You say "till inner 2 subqueries it totally works fine and show about 16 results"  and then you say : "when I add the third and final outer query then nothing shows up". Please, check is there a value PID  in table Person that is the same as this 16 PID values

Comment: yes I copied one of those PID's and directly selected the name of person with that pid and yes it showed the name

Comment: colum PID in M_Cast is of what data type ?

Comment: varchar I guess

Comment: Please can you try this: `select p.Name 
from Person p 
where trim(p.PID, ' ') in (select trim(mc.PID, ' ')
                from M_Cast mc 
                where mc.MID in (select m.MID 
                                 from Movie m 
                                 where lower(title)='anand' ))`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, would you please elaborate what was the problem?

Comment: @SudhanshuRaturi hope that the explanation was ok. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MOVIE.title, person.name
FROM (MOVIE INNER JOIN mcast ON MOVIE.MID = mcast.MID) INNER JOIN person ON mcast.PID = person.PID
WHERE (((MOVIE.title)="ANAND"));

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct p.name  [Actors in Anand]
Movie m
join M_Cast mc on mc.MID=m.MID
join Person p on p.PID=mc.PID
where m.title="Anand"
order by p.name
```

Comment: Please provide more background in your answer